# When should I remove an answer I posted?

Tags: discussion, deleting, up-votes

Yesterday I posted [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148110/22413) to [What causes the following gaps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148099/22413).  Later @egreg posted an answer, which in my opinion is far superior to mine.  Much to my bafflement, people are still upvoting my answer.  This makes me think that some view my answer as contributing something of merit.

So now I'm in a quandary.  Should I remove my answer?  Or does the community feel it has sufficient merit to stay in place?

What should one do when one has decided that his answer is really a non-answer?

Comment: In this case, since the [OP says](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148099/what-causes-the-following-gaps#comment336221_148110) it's +1 , you are safe and even it shows a different direction, BTW community takes care of non-answers but it's in answerer's judgement also.

Answer (score 12):

The fact that **egreg** posted a better answer that you did doesn't mean that your answer is wrong. It's actually good, which is why people upvote it :)

The system likes having more answers to one question, as long as they are not seriously wrong, non-answers or ridiculous. However, only the non-answers should be flagged and removed. It's then the person who asks and the community who decide which answers is better.